# Passing vector with multiple values into R function to generate data frame

Tags: r

I have a table, called table_wo_nas, with multiple columns, one of which is titled ID. For each value of ID there are many rows. I want to write a function that for input x will output a data frame containing the number of rows for each ID, with column headers ID and nobs respectively as below for x <- c(2,4,8).

> ```
> ##   id nobs
> ## 1  2 1041
> ## 2  4  474
> ## 3  8  192
> ```

This is what I have. It works when x is a single value (ex. 3), but not when it contains multiple values, for example 1:10 or c(2,5,7).  I receive the warning "In ID[counter] <- x : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".  I've just started learning R and have been struggling with this for a week and have searched manuals, this site, Google, everything.  Can someone help please?

```
counter <- 1
ID <- vector("numeric") ## contain x
nobs <- vector("numeric") ## contain nrow
for (i in x) {
    r <- subset(table_wo_nas, ID %in% x) ## create subset for rows of ID=x
    ID[counter] <- x ## add x to ID
    nobs[counter] <- nrow(r) ## add nrow to nobs
    counter <- counter + 1 } ## loop
result <- data.frame(ID, nobs) ## create data frame
```

Comment: You can try `tmp<-table_wo_nas[table_wo_nas$ID %in% x,];as.data.frame(table(tmp$ID))`. There are several other ways to do what you want, either in base R or using `dplyr`, `data.table` and other packages.

Comment: Thank you! The data frame generated has column names Var1 and Freq, but I can use the names() function to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R,

```
# To make a named vector, either:
tmp <- sapply(split(table_wo_nas, table_wo_nas$ID), nrow) 

# OR just:
tmp <- table(table_wo_nas$ID)

# AND
# arrange into data.frame
nobs_df <- data.frame(ID = names(tmp), nobs = tmp)
```

Alternately, coerce the table into a `data.frame` directly, and rename:

```
nobs_df <- data.frame(table(table_wo_nas$ID))
names(nobs_df) <- c('ID', 'nobs')
```

If you only want certain rows, subset:

```
nobs_df[c(2, 4, 8), ]
```

There are many, many more options; these are just a few.

---

With `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
table_wo_nas %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(nobs = n())
```

If you only want certain IDs, add on a `filter`:

```
table_wo_nas %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(nobs = n()) %>% filter(ID %in% c(2, 4, 8))
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing I don't understand is why this doesn't seem to work if I want to calculate something other than nrow. For example, this doesn't work:    tmp <- sapply(split(table_wo_nas, table_wo_nas$ID), mean)

Comment: You can, but you need more complicated syntax, because you can't pass `mean` a whole data.frame. Instead, you insert an anonymous function: `sapply(split(table_wo_nas, table_wo_nas$ID), function(x){mean(x$someVariable)})`, which allows you to index and generally do more complicated things. There are lots of [tutorials on the `*apply` functions](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/) that may be helpful. Ultimately you've just got to play around with them, though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward if you just use `table` again:

```
tbl <- table(    table_wo_nas[ , 'ID'] )
data.frame( IDs = names(tbl),  nobs= tbl)
```

Could also get a quick answer although with different column names using:

```
as.data.frame(table( table_wo_nas[ , 'ID'] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  x=c(2,4,8)
  count_of_id=0
   #df is your data frame table_wo_nas
count_of<-function(x)
{for(i in 1 : length(x))
 {count_of_id[i]<-length(which(df$id==x[i])) #find out the n of rows for each unique value of x
  }
 df_1<-cbind(id,count_of_id)
return(df_1)
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what this does?